# Cannot append to a file from bash script

Tags: bash

if I run only this - it works as expected

```
user_conf=( "USER_CONFIG_FILE=user_conf.sh" 
"USER_CONFIG_FILE=user_conf.sh" "USER_CONFIG_FILE=user_conf.sh" )
USER_CONFIG_FILE="user_conf.sh"
echo "${user_conf[@]}"
for i in "${user_conf[@]}"; do
    echo "$i" >> "$USER_CONFIG_FILE"
done
echo "User config file initiated."
```

However when I run it in my [install.sh](https://github.com/scgbckbone/wenv/blob/master/install.sh) nothing is appended to desired config file. The same code as above is at the bottom of install.sh. You can also see tere that I first tried to to it with echo-appends on multiple places(commented out lines) but only two echo statements above separator line (===) worked - not below that line. I really have no idea what causes it. What have I missed?

EDIT:
Do not worry to run install.sh (without args).
It only creates one entry in your .bash_aliases and creates directory 'wenv' in your HOME. You can delete both afterwards.

Comment: You just have to figure out what directory you're in when you that executes. `make_base_dir` calls `make_log_file` which does a `cd` but never changes back to the previous directory.

Comment: I'm so spoiled with python context managers. Thanks a lot. Should I resolve myself or do you want to add answer (i would mark it as correct). Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to figure out what directory you're in when you that executes. make_base_dir calls make_log_file which does a cd but never changes back to the previous directory.